# Show that all the zeros of $p(z)$ lie inside the disk $|z|=3$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that all the zeros of $p(z)=z^3-2z^2-z+5$ lie inside the disk
>   $|z|=3$

Using Rouche's theorem, how do I pick a $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)| \ge |g(z)|$ for $|z|=3$?

For example, $|f(z)=z^3+5|$ and $|f(z)=-2z^2-z+5|$ are both greater than $|g(z)=-2z^2-z|$ and $|g(z)=z^3|$, respectively. Does it  matter what form $f(z)$ takes?

Comment: $|z^3| = 27$ is clearly greater than $|-2z^2-z+5| \leq 2\cdot 9 + 3 + 5 = 17$, which is the opposite of what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: There are two versions of Rouche's:

1) If $\lvert f(z) - g(z) \rvert < \lvert f(z) \rvert$, then $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeroes;

2) If $\lvert f(z) \rvert < \lvert g(z) \rvert$, then $f+g$ and $f$ have the same number of zeroes.

It looks like you are using the 2nd statement; I was using (1) (but not quite correctly).

You want to choose an $f$ in which you can guarantee that $f$ has 3 zeroes that lie inside $\lvert z \rvert = 3$. 
You suggested 2 options:

(1) $f(z) = z^3$ and $g(z) = -2z^3 - z + 5$, so:

> $\lvert -2z^3 - z + 5 \rvert \leq \lvert -2z^2 \rvert + \lvert -z \rvert + 5 = 26 < 27 = \lvert z^3 \rvert$

And we know for sure that $z^3$ has 3 zeroes at $z = 0$, which is definitely inside the disk $\lvert z \rvert \leq 3$. Then $z^3$ and $z^3 - 2z^2 - z + 5$ have the same number of zeroes, so this would work.

(2) $f(z) = z^3 + 5$ and $g(z) = -2z^2 - z$, so:

> $\lvert -2z^2 - z \rvert = \lvert z(-2z - 1) \rvert = \lvert z \rvert \lvert -2z - 1 \rvert \leq 3(\lvert 2z \rvert + 1) = 21 < 22 = \lvert \lvert z^3 \rvert - 5 \rvert \leq \lvert z^3 + 5\rvert $

We also know that $z^3 + 5 = 0$ has three solutions inside $\lvert z \rvert < 3$ since $z^3 = (r^3\text{cos}(3\theta) + ir^3\text{sin}(3\theta)) = 5 \implies r = 5^{1/3}$. We know that $3 > 5^{1/3}$ since $27 > 5$, so this suggestion would also work.

Tldr: Both of your suggestions would work (there's more than one right answer with questions like this), but I like the first one better for a few reasons. First, it's more obvious to me that $f(z) = z^3$ has 3 zeroes inside $\lvert z \rvert = 3$. It looks like $f(z) = z^3 + 5$ also has three zeroes inside the disk, but you would have to use DeMoivre's Formula to find them, which is more work, so why not use the first one? Also, it seems to me that the first inequality is easier to calculate. Finally, although it doesn't really apply to this question, if you have an expression with all its zeroes at the origin, you can try to use it for a disk of any size.

Comment: Why $|z^3| \ge |z^3-2z^2-z+5|$, not $|z^3| \ge |-2z^2-z+5|$?

Comment: I just realized I used the wrong form of Rouche's, will edit!

Comment: Completely changed my answer, thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|=3$ we have $|p(z)-z^3| \le 2 \cdot 9 + 3 + 5 = 26 < 27 = |z^3|$.

Hence Rouché tells use that $p$ and $z \mapsto z^3$ have the same number
of zeros inside $|z| =3$.

Generally a good first try is to see if Rouché applies with the leading term 'removed'.